# ArgumentError (Could not parse the PKCS7: header too long)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sinatra

I am trying to convert a Ruby project that uses Sinatra and WEBrick over to Rails and Passenger.

This code in Sinatra works fine:

```
world.mount_proc("/profile") { |req, res|
  p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(req.body)
}
```

I have converted this code to run in a Rails controller:

```
def profile
  p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(request.body)
end
```

The following error is shown when processing the request in Rails:

```
F, [2018-12-14T03:00:01.418176 #30473] FATAL -- : [4a785370-6bbe-4d34-8731-e4fd406f2719] ArgumentError (Could not parse the PKCS7: header too long):
F, [2018-12-14T03:00:01.418255 #30473] FATAL -- : [4a785370-6bbe-4d34-8731-e4fd406f2719]   
F, [2018-12-14T03:00:01.418354 #30473] FATAL -- : [4a785370-6bbe-4d34-8731-e4fd406f2719] app/controllers/mdm_controller.rb:224:in `initialize'
```

I am using the same Ruby version for both apps, Ruby 2.5.3p105.

The OpenSSL version is also same for both, OpenSSL (default: 2.1.2).

Why does this work in Sinatra but not work in Rails?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `req.body` and `request.body` are identical?

Comment: yes, both are same

Comment: I don't mean belabor the point, but are you absolutely positive they are 100% bit-for-bit identical? No unintentional newline characters or anything? They aren't processed by the underlying stack differently resulting in imperceptible differences?

Comment: thanks @anothermh I'll check once again and get back to you

Comment: You've got OpenSSL already loaded, take a digest.